# DB server on high resources how to solve it

Tags: mariadb

I have SAAS web application developed in Codeigniter 3, and I have two servers, one to handle http requests and one dedicated to DB.

I am using MariaDB on DB server. I have one database for each client.

Now my issue is my DB server always remain on high, it consume full resources every time so I have restart it everyday.

Even once I do restart ram utilization increases from 10% to 75% in just 10 min at night when no one is online.

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => $DBhost,
'username' => $DBusername,
'password' => $DBpassword,
'database' => $DBname,
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8mb4',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => $encrypt,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => FALSE
);
```

This is db config I use in CI3.
I see I have constant open tables log approx 10000 and Openes log keep on increasing.

Do any one need more details related to anything let me know.

How can I solve this DB resources issue, I get open temp keep on increase without any close.

Following are analyses of 20 minute period

Opens: 174567  Open tables: 10000

Opens: 174614  Open tables: 10000

Comment: Unused RAM doesn't do you any good. Most databases will use as much as they can for caching information. Is this causing you *actual* problems, or are you just worried about the RAM utilization number by itself?

Comment: For further analysis of those values and others, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Answer (score 2):

Being a database per client you've got a large number of tables as your output shows. Given `open_tables` is staying at 10000 and there are still `opened_tables` you've obviously reached your 10000 limit per your setting of [table_open_cache](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#table_open_cache). This can be increased further to keep more tables caches.

Per `opened_tables`, (174614 - 174567) / 20 = 47 tables per minute or just under 1 per second which isn't a huge CPU cost, however with your per client model it shows that `table_open_cache` can be increased further.

For a more complete analysis a complete `show global status` over a time period (20 mins is about the minimum) that isn't just MariaDB warming up would be useful. There are other setting that might need to be change. Ram usage isn't a bad thing (what exact metric are you using), but the most important thing generally is the query response time. Is this a problem?

Tuning is often jumped to as the solution to all performance problems, use the slow query log to gain information about the performance:

In your config file:

[slow_query_log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-overview/)

[slow_query_log_file](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#slow_query_log_file)=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb-slow.log

[log-slow-verbosity=query_plan,explain](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/)

Resolving slow queries with the assistance of table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`), the query, and the explain plan (direct from log for `EXPLAIN query`) can be asked on Stack Overflow. Frequently this just requires the right indexes.